# Why is instantiating python class repeating former actions by other instances before doing new action?

Tags: python, django, interactive

I've tried to represent this issue as good as I can with a custom example.

I've set up a special class that systematically runs through a very large number of steps `from __init__(self)` onward.

Everything seems to work great, **except this very strange problem where every time I call the class, it seems to go back in time and repeat itself with the former two actions before doing the new action.** If I ran it five times, by the fifth time it would repeat the former 4 identical actions before doing the 5th new action, and so forth.

Its a very strange problem. This is python interactive in a django-environment. Hopefully my code example shows the issue fairly well:

```
#file helper_stuff.py
class one_shot_long_process():

    obj=''
    obj2=''

    def init(self, obj, obj2):

        self.obj=obj
        self.obj2=obj2

        self.complex_action()
        self.complex_action_2()

    def complex_action(self):
        '''do lots of things in a row with obj'''

    def complex_action_2(self):
        '''
        Do more stuff, make decisions, loop, etc
        with obj 1, 2
        make entries, do writes

        >>>> WRITE FILES by number (jpegs)
        '''
```

So there you have a basic example of the class. It fetches django models, processes images, and writes them. I've checked fairly closely, and I see no reason for it to repeat in this manner (especially since I am calling the class-instancing directly as shown below)

```
#file interactive_stuff.py    

#!/home/leo/.virtualenvs/illo/bin/python3 -i        
from helper_stuff import one_shot_long_process


>>> one_shot_long_process(obj, obj2)

#WRITES FILE 1.jpg

>>> one_shot_long_process(obj, obj2)

#re-WRITES FILE 1.jpg
#WRITES FILE 2.jpg

>>> one_shot_long_process(obj, obj2)

#re-WRITES FILE 1.jpg
#re-WRITES FILE 2.jpg
#WRITES FILE 3.jpg
```

**This is very strange -- why is calling one_shot_long_process(obj, obj2) afresh still causing former "instances" to repeat themselves? How can I get around this?**

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's in your `complex_action_2` function, which you have given no code for.

Comment: Maybe the issue is my understanding of calling the class (being that I started in php) calling `one_shot_long_process(obj, obj2)` should start the process over every time, correct?

Comment: If you think your understanding is faulty, **post actual code** so we can come to our own conclusions. Right now you're imposing your understanding, good or bad, because all we have to go on is your descriptions and the names of your functions.

Comment: Simple question: If I run a class instance `some_new_class(input)` that never references the outside world except what it is fed it should run new every time, correct? Every time `some_new_class(input)` is run, it should be an entirely new set of data -- there should be no way to reference the old data that was contained in the previous one -- isn't that basic SCOPE matters? I'm asking this way so I don't have to post a mountain of code.

Comment: But can't you see that the answer to that depends what the function is doing? Maybe it's storing data in class scope, or somewhere else. We don't know unless you show us.

Comment: It's not a simple question; it's an impossible one. **Your understanding is incorrect**. The answer to your question is: it depends. What does it depend on? It depends on what's in that function. I don't know what you think is supposed to be happening or what you're asking, but there's no way to answer the question you have asked.

Comment: "a class instance... that never references the outside world except what it is fed" -- but what is it fed? Did you give it [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)? Are you using class variables instead of instance variables, as Daniel suggested? Those types of references persist in memory, which is the outside world, whether they start in the class or are passed in via \_\_init__ or something else.

Comment: It also doesn't help that you're using incorrect terms. "calling the class... should start the process over every time". Do you mean [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))? Then no. Otherwise, what is the meaning of "process"? I'm trying to help you understand that you're putting up barriers to anyone actually answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some actual code I can only guess, but I'll give it a shot.

You are not starting "afresh", because `one_shot_long_process.obj` and `one_shot_long_process.obj2` are [class variables, not instance variables.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Let me illustrate with an example.

```
class Foo():

    l = []
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.l.append(x)
        print self.l

class Bar():

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.l = []
        self.l.append(x)
        print self.l

Foo(4) # prints [4]
Foo(4) # prints [4, 4]
Bar(4) # prints [4]
Bar(4) # prints [4]
```

As others have said, without some actual code, it's impossible to tell. In the code you posted, it doesn't make a difference.

On a side note, the [common naming convention for classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) is to use `CapWords`, i.e. in your case `OneShotLongProcess`.

Comment: This is pricesly where I was wrong and where the issue was. I thought calling Foo made it new every time! Very much appreciated thank you.